# How to use LIMIT in getQuery

Tags: jdatabase

Given the desired SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM #__tablename LIMIT 5
```

How do I use $query to accomplish it?

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();       
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->nameQuote('*'));
$query->from($db->nameQuote('#__tablename'));      
$db->setQuery($query);      
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both J2.5 and 3.x will vary.

#### Joomla 2.5:

```
$db->setQuery($query, 0, 5);
```

where `0` is the **start/offset** and `5` is the **limit**

#### Joomla 3.x

```
$query->setLimit(5);
```

This also accepts a 2nd argument which is the **offset**, but is not required