# How to separate database results into 2 columns?

Tags: php, database

I saw the examples of how to do the odd even way, but I want the order to flow from one whole column to the next and not alternating left to right for each alphabetical item. Can this be done?

Here is the query

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$db->setQuery('SELECT title, introtext 
               FROM #__content
               WHERE introtext LIKE "%Still Airing%"
               ORDER BY title ASC');
$row = $db->loadAssocList();
```

I tried dividing it by 2, but then how do you get each column to appear in html?

```
$half = count($row) / 2;
```

What I was thinking was I could use the variable to list that number of items in each column (or table tds) , but don't know the syntax or if I'm doing it right. Like list $half items and then the rest in the next column.

The introtext is just a filter, I only want the titles displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [array_chunk()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) with the row count cut in half then rounded-up will ensure that the second column always has equal or one less row than the first column.

HTML tables should only be used to display "tabular" data.  Since you are building two non-tabular lists, it would be more appropriate to employ other tags (several different tags may be appropriate).

Demo (copy-paste my snippet into phptester.net to see the rich-text result)

```
// $resultset = $db->loadAssocList();  ...I am supplying my own sample data
$resultset = [
    ['title' => 'A', 'introtext' => 'A intro'],
    ['title' => 'B', 'introtext' => 'B intro'],
    ['title' => 'C', 'introtext' => 'C intro'],
    ['title' => 'D', 'introtext' => 'D intro'],
    ['title' => 'E', 'introtext' => 'E intro']
];

$halves = array_chunk($resultset, ceil(count($resultset) / 2));

foreach ($halves as $half) {
    echo '<div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; border: solid 1px black; padding: 2px;">';
        foreach ($half as $row) {
            echo '<div style="border: 1px solid blue; padding: 2px;">';
                echo '<p style="background-color: green;">' , $row['title'] , '</p>';
                echo '<p style="background-color: yellow;">' , $row['introtext'] , '</p>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Output:

[image]

---

After a bit of back and forth in the comments, here is the direct approach to output only the `title` values as two columns in the desired arrangement:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select("title")
            ->from("#__content")
            ->where("introtext LIKE '%Still Airing%'")
            ->order("title");
// echo $query->dump();  // uncomment if you want to see the rendered query
$db->setQuery($query);
$resultset = $db->loadColumn();

$halves = array_chunk($resultset, ceil(count($resultset) / 2));

foreach ($halves as $half) {
    echo '<div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; border: solid 1px black; padding: 2px;">';
        echo '<div>' , implode('</div><div>', $half) , '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Note, by using Joomla's query building methods, it is easier to diagnose problems by printing `$query->dump()`.

Comment: Not working for me for some reason, nothing displaying. Will play with it. I tried running 3 queries - 1 to get $count (worked), next to limit results to $count, and then 3rd to limit results to $count offset by $count, then echo rowa & rowb in html - but i kept getting an error around the order by in the query. **....LIMIT ' . $count . ' OFFSET ' . $count . ' ORDER BY title ASC');**

Comment: That is a separate issue, of course.  Please show me your query buliding code as a 3v4l.org link.  I am on the train to work.  Support time is limited.

Comment: If that WHERE clause is fed a variable, it is not employing secure practices. https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22712/12352 ...if it is static text, it is okay.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/t0lRA

Comment: Are you using https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/5646/12352 ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4974639/2943403

Comment: Had module unpublished duh, now getting your code to display, but I'm confused on how to get results into it? Count showed 215 results, but this number and the results will change periodically. Do i need to manually enter results to use this?

Comment: You never need to count the rows or perform any query limiting (unless you are implementing a pagination technique).  Just perform the one query that you posted in your question, and save the resultset as `$resultset = $db->loadAssocList();`  I will urge you to use Joomla query building methods (purely as a matter of "toeing the line" (although running a raw query will technically be more efficient).

Comment: https://3v4l.org/4LLLj  Just keep getting the same boxes you show in description. No titles appear. All I want displayed is the title.

Comment: That's even simpler... https://3v4l.org/jBMjf  No more help for a while (at work).

Comment: did you notice that I changed the query to only include one column and resultset building method?  `$db->loadColumn()`

Comment: Got it, got rid of abcde line on change and it's displaying! Thanks! If you want to edit in the code i will accept as answer. https://3v4l.org/6XuZX